# How do I query two fields in an embedded array?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like the one below. The `periods` field defines periods the user had access to some data.

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("51878ecc0e9528429ab6e7cf"),
   "name" : "Peter Flack",
   "periods":[
      {
         "from":1,
         "to":2
      },
      {
         "from":4,
         "to":6
      },
      {
         "from":10,
         "to":12
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to determine if an arbitrary period is within any of the periods in the `period` field. I have tried the following:

```
db.subs.find({"periods.from" : {$gte : 1}, "periods.to" : {$lte : 12}, "periods.from" : {$lte : 12}, "periods.to" : {$gte : 1}})
```

This query returns the document, since there is one element in the array with `from` >= 1 and antoher element with `to` <= 12.

But, I want to get back the document only if both `from` and `to` **in the same element** match the criteria.

How would I write the query to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use $elemMatch : elemMatch match for the params in each element of the array.

```
Mongo > db.subs.find({periods : {$elemMatch : { from : {$gte : 1, $lte:12}, to : {$gte : 1, $lte : 12} }}}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51878ecc0e9528429ab6e7cf"),
    "name" : "Peter Flack",
    "periods" : [
        {
            "from" : 1,
            "to" : 2
        },
        {
            "from" : 4,
            "to" : 6
        },
        {
            "from" : 10,
            "to" : 12
        }
    ]
}
Mongo > db.subs.find({periods : {$elemMatch : { from : {$gte : 2, $lte : 4}, to : {$gte : 10, $lte : 12} }}}).pretty()
no result
```

Comment: Sorry, did not work. As I understand it $elemMatch is for projektion. That is, it only affects what fields in the document to return and not if the document should be returned or not. Looking in the documentation it is only used in the second argument of the find() function.

Comment: @luttkens `$elemMatch` is also a query operator.  Docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch).  As you wrote the query it's working fine, I think you've got your `$gte` and `$lte` operators swapped to do what you're actually looking for.

Comment: @luttkens : $elemMatch will work.
I have modified my earlier comment, please check

Comment: @Abhishek if you use it and say from 1 to 1 nothing returns but it is within a document. well actually the question is confusing cause 1) it states "within the periods" but 2) it says matches (i guess exactly matches from and to.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are talking about : { from : {$gte : 1}, to : {$lte : 1 }}
For the above query, I can't see any document that is matching the criteria.
Please explain, if I missed something

Comment: my point is that if you are looking for subs that worked in January, this would not do it. Jan is within Jan thru Feb

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Thanks, I see now that the problem was the my logic from the beginning was wrong. I need to have four criterias in order find out if a period is within another period. Like this: `db.subs.find({periods : {$elemMatch : {from : {$gte : 1}, to : {$lte : 12}, f
rom $lt : 12}, to : {$gt :1}}}})`.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: I updated my question so that the logic is correct. Please update your answer and will accept it! Thanks for your time!

Comment: db.subs.find({periods : {$elemMatch : { from : {$gte : 1, $lte:12}, to : {$gte :  1, $lte : 12} }}}).pretty()